# How to configure a View as Temporal

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to query a view *"EntityResume"* that is relying on historical tables.

But as soon as this view is part of a linq-to-entities query using the method `TemporalAsOf` I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Temporal query is trying to use
> navigation to an entity 'EntityResume' which itself doesn't map to
> temporal table. Either map the entity to temporal table or use join
> manually to access it.

Here is the query:

```
this.Context.Deltas
            .TemporalAsOf(date)
            .Include(delta => delta.EntityResumes)
```

**"Detla"* is not a temporal table.*

I haven't found any way to configure my *"EntityResume"* entity to indicate entity framework that it is indeed a view that rely on temporal data and on which sql server can apply `AS OF`.

Here is the entity configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityResume>().ToView(nameof(EntityResume)).HasKey(resume => new {resume.Id, resume.LangueId});
```

Comment: Is the view `EntityResume` a database view? I'm fairly certain that `AS OF` doesn't work against a view, only directly against a temporal table. You could try a table valued function.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: no, [`FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` works against views](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table#using-views-with-as-of-subclause-in-temporal-queries) -- this is in fact one of the major selling points of temporal queries, that you can have a view that joins together a bunch of temporal tables, and then apply `AS OF` to the view to have a consistent view of all tables at once. (As to EF support, I have no idea.)

Comment: Oh wow I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging with the help of a coworker we finally found a solution, or I should say a trick.

Be aware that this solution is **not possible** if you are using ***code first*** approach.

The first thing to do was to declare the view as a table in the configuration. By doing so we can take advantage of the `tableBuilder` parameter of `ToTable` (which is not present in `ToView`).

```
  builder
    .ToTable(nameof(EntityResume), "MySchema", tableBuilder => tableBuilder.IsTemporal())
    .HasKey(resume => new {resume.Id, resume.LangueId});
```

After that you will have to add two column in your view projection: `null as PeriodStart, null as PeriodEnd`.
Without it, entity framework won't allow you to use the `IsTemporal()` method. But those columns will never be used by sql server.

Finally, you will be able to use your view with the temporal methods in your query.

```
        await this.Context.Deltas
            .Select(delta => new
            {
                delta,
                resumes = this.Context.EntityResumes.TemporalAsOf(date).Where(resume => resume.Id == delta.EntityId).ToList()
            })
```

I moved the *EntityResumes* property from the `Include` to the `Select` as *Delta* table is not a temporal table and Temporal methods can only be applied on `DataSet` of `temporal table`.

Comment: Wouldn't this return *all* resumes, not the resume's for that delta? If Delta -> EntityResume is one to many then would that be `resumes = Context.EntityResumes.TemporalAsOf(date).Where(x => x.DeltaId == delta.Id).ToList()`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, i chopped off too much of my code for the example.
Thanks i'm going to correct that right away :)